# (noun to) + (verbal noun) vs (noun to) + (verb) when there's normally a noun after (noun + to)

Tags: grammar, verbs, nouns, to-infinitive, verbal-noun

I'll give you an example:

"I want to get an access to _____"

Should I fill it with "doing" or "do"?

Because normally after the "access to" collocation we use a noun, e.g "access to games", "access to a horizontal bar".

So, should I use "doing" as a verbal noun because there's only nouns used after that collocation, or should I use "do", because somewhy I feel, like it's an option too?

Would it be a huge horrible mistake if I say "give me an access to playing"?

Comment: Yes: "access" normally takes no complement at all, or else a preposition phrase as complement, but not a clause.

Comment: I asked you the other day, and am asking you again: please use capitals with the first person pronoun. It's very jarring to native speakers to see i for I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word **access** is usually not countable, so we would say:

> I would like to get access to {something}.

No article.

You cannot get "access to" **doing** or **playing**.

You can get access to {something} **(in order) to** be able to do something.

> I would like to get access to the gym (in order) to use the exercise equipment.

The phrase **in order** is optional.

> I would like to get access to the members area of the website to play the online games there.  Please give me access to it.

Comment: So, can i skip, for example, "to the gym" part and just say something like "I would like to get access to use the exercise equipment"

Comment: You could only omit **to the gym** if your words would be clearly understood in context.  If you're speaking to someone whose job involves giving access to the gym on a daily basis, chances are very good that your remark would be understood :)

Comment: oh now I get it... 
So access can't be applied to actions, only to subjects
whereas the words "can" and "may" can be applied to actions, e.g "can I use that equipment?"
So in my example I had to say "can I play games?".


But what do you think by the way, "can I play games" wouldn't mean exactly the same thing as "Give me access to play games", because in first sentence one asks for permission, but in the second one they are forcing the person to give them permission

Comment: Or maybe the alternative for forcing a person to give permission would be "let me". I know it's all actually asking for access but there're some emotional differences in meanings.